# Java AWT Clipboard русские буквы

Tags: java, utf-8

Нужно как-то русские символы из Java переслать в Clipboard, но чего-то страшная ересь на выходе получается.

```
go.pasteRus("/dump TradeSkillFrameEditBox:SetText(\"Трансмутация: извечная жизнь в тьму\")")
```

Функция pasteRus (Java/Scala) выглядит вот так.

```
  def pasteRus(message: String): Unit = {
    val str = new java.lang.String(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), Charset.forName("cp1251"));
    val output = new StringSelection(str)
    clipboard.setContents(output, null)
```

На выходе получаю страшную ересь, уже все кодировки перепробовал что были в официальном мануале - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html

```
/dump TradeSkillFrameEditBox:SetText("РўСЂР°РЅСЃРјСѓС‚Р°С†РёСЏ: РёР·РІРµС‡РЅР°СЏ Р¶РёР·РЅСЊ РІ С‚СЊРјСѓ")
```

Есть у кого свежие идеи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Начинать нужно с ответа на вопрос** в какой кодировке у вас написан текст:

> Трансмутация: извечная жизнь в тьму

По сути это ответ на вопрос в какой кодировке у вас работает редактор, в котором вы пишете код. Либо это CP-1251 (Windows Cyrillic) или UTF-8, в теории конечно может быть и ISO-8859 или даже CP-866 (терминал Windows). Ну, ок - допустим это CP-1251.

**Второй не менее важный вопрос** в какой кодировке у вас выводит текст ваше AWT приложение, опять таки возможны варианты CP-1251 или UTF-8. Обычно совпадает с дефолтной `Locale` установленной в JVM.

Теперь, когда засылаем в клипборд ваш текст, его надо перекодировать в кодировку совпадающую с кодировкой AWT приложения. Конвертировать нужно так (в Scala не силен):

```
public String convert(String inString, String inCharset, String outCharset) {
    byte[] bytes=inString.getBytes(inCharset);
    return new String(bytes, outCharset);
}
```

Например: `convert(s, "cp1251", "utf-8") //перекодировка из кодировки Windows в UTF-8`

Дальше полученный `String` уже надо отправить в клипборд

Comment: Редактор IDEA (UTF-8). А вот "второй не менее важный вопрос" дал хлеб для умных идей.. Кодировка по умолчанию была "en_US.UTF-8", после перестановки на Locale.setDefault(new Locale("ru_RU.UTF-8")); В загрузчике приложения мгновенно исправила ошибку. Даже не пришлось в ручную перешаманивать кодировки.   Спасибо большое!